# Lizmap/QGIS Server : cache management (seeding)

Tags: qgis-server, cache, lizmap

On Debian/Apache, I succeed in installing QGIS Server and Lizmap. I am a little surprised by the poor performance that I can observe currently. They must probably be explained by a bad configuration that I need to improve. I am thinking in particular of the cache.
I'm trying to follow this page from the doc:
https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/admin/cache.html#seeding
If I understand correctly, I would benefit from generating the tile cache.

When I do:

```
lizmap-web-client-3.6.3# php lizmap/console.php wmts:cache:seed -v -f dr0 drills_2154 EPSG:2154 1 7
```

I get :

```
In Input.php line 76:
   [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
   Not enough arguments (missing: "TileMatrixMax").
Exception trace:
   at /var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3/lizmap/vendor/symfony/console/Input/Input.php:76
  Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input->validate() at /var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3/lizmap/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:293
  Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3/lizmap/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1040
  Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3/lizmap/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:301
  Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3/lizmap/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
  Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3/lizmap/vendor/jelix/jelix/lib/jelix/Scripts/ModulesCommands.php:48
  Jelix\Scripts\ModulesCommands::run() at /var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3/lizmap/console.php:2

wmts:cache:seed [--dry-run] [--bbox BBOX] [-f|--force] [--] <repository> <project> <layers> <TileMatrixSet> <TileMatrixMin> <TileMatrixMax>
```

And when I try to add a layer as an argument:

```
lizmap-web-client-3.6.3# php lizmap/console.php wmts:cache:seed -v -f dr0 forages_2154 Ouvrage_a_Realiser_Pt EPSG:2154 1 7
```

I get :

```
The cache in not available!
The WMTS Service has not been initialized!
The WMTS Service has been initialized!
No layers configured with cache!
```

Answer (score 0):

Following to my previous question, i'm taking the liberty to specify when i make :

```
/var/www/lizmap/lizmap-web-client-3.6.3# php lizmap/console.php project:load
```

I get :

```
Enter the repository lizmaptest
Get the project zios
1 request(s) return success for the project zios
Enter the repository aero
Get the project aero_v2
1 request(s) return success for the project aero_v2
Enter the repository dr0
Get the project forages
1 request(s) return success for the project forages
Get the project forages_2154
1 request(s) return success for the project forages_2154
Get the project dr0
1 request(s) return success for the project dr0
Get the project forages_2154_with_fond
1 request(s) return success for the project forages_2154_with_fond
```